# Sumar sobre las columnas que no están en las listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un marco de datos `df` con columnas con el siguiente patrón: `#number - letter` y quiero añadir en una nueva columna `other` que hace la suma de de las columnas que no están en `letter_table1` y `letter_table2`:

```
TEXT, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
a,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
b,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
c,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
d,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
e,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
f,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
g,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
h,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
i,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
j,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
```

pro ejemplo

```
letter_table1 = [H]
letter_table2 = [I]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? Por el momento lo he intentado:

```
        df_sum['others'] = df.loc[:,~df.isin(tableau_lettres1, tableau_lettres2)].sum(axis=1)
```

así como:

```
        df_sum['others'] = df.loc[:,df.drop(tableau_lettres1, tableau_lettres2)].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tenías. Haciendo un simple `df.drop(columns=...)` y pasando como argumento la lista con los nombres de columnas a eliminar (puedes crear esa lista concatenando las dos que tienes), el resultado es un dataframe al que faltan esas columnas.

Basta hacer `.sum()` sobre el resultado de ese dataframe para obtener lo que buscas, si te entendí bien. Mira:

```
>>> print(df)
      A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
TEXT                           
a     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
b     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
c     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
d     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
e     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
f     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
g     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
h     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
i     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3
j     1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3

>>> letter_table1 = ["H"]
>>> letter_table2 = ["I"]
>>> df.drop(columns=letter_table1 + letter_table2).sum()
A    10
B    10
C    10
D    20
E    20
F    20
G    30
dtype: int64
```